# build VS build_depend

Tags: ros, package.xml, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I saw in different tutorials two different way to add dependencies in package.xml:

```
<build_depend>package</build_depend>
<build_export_depend>package</build_export_depend>
<exec_depend>package</exec_depend>
```

and

```
<build>package</build>
```

I would like to know the difference, and which one I should use.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351892/build-vs-build_depend/) by [Mickael](https://answers.ros.org/users/54727/mickael/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I would like to know the difference, and which one I should use.

The difference is that `build_depend` et al. are legal values, while `build` is not a legal value for an element in a package manifest.

Perhaps the author of the "different tutorials" you mention (please *always* link to what you mention, we cannot guess) intended to actually write `depend`, as that would be a legal value.

See [REP-149: Package Manifest Format Three Specification - Dependency tags](https://ros.org/reps/rep-0149.html#dependency-tags) for allowed elements and what their purpose is.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0